# New Filemanager in EE7 and Assets-Addon

Tags: assets, file-manager, eeharbor, ee7

For years we are using the Assets-Addon by EEHarbor as our filemanager. Now we have a rather big file-structure with maybe 4000, 5000 files (mostly images). Now with EE7 a [new Filemanager](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest//control-panel/file-manager/file-manager.html) has been released. I have two questions about this:

- We want to abandon Assets and just use the EE-filemanager. Will this lead to problems (like broken paths), or can we just do/try it?
- Does the replacement of Assets with EE7-filemanager make sense, or are there advantages using Assets instead of the EE7-filemanager?

Thanks in advance for any hint!